# Bulk add featured image to existing Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have cca 4500 posts in my Wordpress backend. Some posts doesn't have featured image. I was wondering is there any solution to bulk add featured image (placeholder if there is no "real" image)? I'm talking about backend, I now that I can do on front end but need way to add featured image in the backend if featured image is empty.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using 3 ways.

1. Using plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/

2. Or you can show dummy image to your code (when there is no featured image found)

check below code for front-end

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} else { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

3. AJAX in Admin (In custom form) - You can also achieve same using creating one option page in backend where you can give form with one image field, and on save you can update featured image if blank found using ajax.